# Swift: Crash when Printing

Tags: ios, swift

```
let myPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Settings", ofType: ".png")

print(myPath!)
```

Why does it crash when I'm trying to print this?

Comment: It lets you Build it but when accessing it on the Phone it crashes

Comment: You are force unwrapping an optional myPath object and you're trying to print this even if it is actually nil. Why do you need an image's path though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crash is the famous *Unexpected found `nil` while unwrapping ...* error. Don't use exclamation marks unless it's guaranteed that the value is not `nil`.

Either the file does not exist or (most likely) your *type* (extension) is  `png` not `.png`

```
let myPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Settings", ofType: "png")
```

However nowadays the URL related API is preferable

```
let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Settings", withExtension: "png")
```

Comment: One can argue that you should force-unwrap the result of `Bundle.main.url (or path) because you are attempting to load a file you expect to be there. If the file isn't there, it's a setup issue with the project (or a type) and you want the app to crash immediately so you can fix the problem with the project (or the typo).

Answer (score 1):

My simple guess is that myPath is nil, so it crashes at the nil pointer exception. Remove the exclamation mark and use:

```
print(myPath)
```

If it prints nil, then you have your answer.

Comment: Do you know why it is nil?